# Swift array with mixed elements,why return different result

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var arr1: Array = [34, 8.7, "hello"]
var arr2: Array<Any> = [34, 8.7, "hello"]

println(arr1)
println(arr2)
```

> [34, 8.699999999999999, hello] 
>   [34, 8.7, hello]

different result,anyone can explain it?

Comment: Floating point precision. The computer can represent numbers only to a certain precision. 8.7 and 8.6999999999999 are essentially the same, though I can only speculate why they are displayed differently.

Comment: As @vacawama has noted, you can simplify this question to "why do `println(NSNumber(double: 8.7))` and `println(Double(8.7))` give different results?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `arr1`, since you didn't specify the type and you have `Foundation` imported, Swift made the array type `[NSObject]`.  Then, the types of `34`, `8.7`, and `"hello"` are `NSNumber`, `NSNumber`, and `NSString` respectively.

For whatever reason, an `NSNumber` with a value of `8.7` prints as `8.699999999999999`.  Try this is a Playground:

```
var a: NSNumber = 8.7
println(a)            // prints 8.699999999999999
```

In `arr2`, the values have the types `Int`, `Double`, and `String`, so the `8.7` prints as you would expect:

```
var b: Double = 8.7
println(b)           // prints 8.7
```

As Matt Gibson states in the comments:

> the output difference may be because NSNumber's description method
>   formats the number as "%0.16g"; if you do NSString(format: "%0.16g",
>   8.7) gives you "8.699999999999999". I'm sure they're both just the same double "underneath".

To test the theory that they are the same number underneath, I did:

```
if (arr1[1] as NSNumber).doubleValue == (arr2[1] as Double) {
    println("same")
}
```

and this does indeed print `"same"`.

Comment: I think the output difference may be because [NSNumber's `description` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/descriptionWithLocale:) formats the number as "%0.16g"; if you do `NSString(format: "%0.16g", 8.7)` gives you "8.699999999999999". I'm sure they're both just the same double "underneath".